# SNMP Get Request returns NULL

Tags: snmp, mib, snmp4j

I am newbie to SNMP, I am trying to use SNMP Operations, I am using http://techdive.in/snmp/snmp4j-snmp-get-example code But I am not able to get the expected output. I am getting NULL response as below:

### Output:

SNMP GET Demo
Sending Request to Agent...
Got Response from Agent
Snmp Get Response = [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = Null]

As I am trying to get sysDescr for OID of MIB RFC 1213, the expected output should be as below:

### Expected Output:

SNMP GET Demo
Sending Request to Agent...
Got Response from Agent
Snmp Get Response = [1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0 = Test Agent Simulator]

Where am I going wrong? Any help would be highly Aprreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try to use `snmpget` from net-snmp-tools package (download [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/net-snmp/) or install from distro repo if you have linux).

```
snmpget -v2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0
```

Replace community and host with actual values.

It should produce something like this:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux XYZ 3.10.0-327.13.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP
```

If you got error, then adjust hostname/community to correct values and make sure that SNMP agent is running on target machine and firewall allows you to connect.

**UPDATE**

You can even use `snmpwalk` to make sure that `sysDescr` OID is available:

```
snmpwalk -v2c -c public localhost 1.3.6.1.2.1.1
```

Output:

```
SNMPv2-MIB::sysDescr.0 = STRING: Linux XYZ Thu Mar 31 16:04:38 UTC 2016 x86_64
SNMPv2-MIB::sysObjectID.0 = OID: NET-SNMP-MIB::netSnmpAgentOIDs.10
```